# Loop thru a nested collection in a repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a list object

```
List<Documents>
```

, and inside that I have another list list of accounts.

```
List<Accounts>
```

From my codebehind I connect List to a repeater control

```
rptDocumentListings.DataSource = List<Documents>;
rptDocumentListings.DataBind();
```

While the repeater loops thru each item in List I want it to also loop thru each nest list of accounts, and then render out with 
 tags. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
//in the dataRepeater
<%# parseAccountNumbers(Eval("Accounts"))%>

//method in codebehind
public string parseAccountNumbers(List<Account> accounts)
    {
        string allAccounts = string.Empty;

        foreach (var item in accounts)
        {
            allAccounts += string.Format("{0}<br />", item.AccountNumber);
        }

        return allAccounts;
    }
```

The error I get is 'Cannot convert from from 'Object' to 'System.Collections.List'
Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
<%# parseAccountNumbers(Eval("Accounts"))%>
```

To

```
<%# parseAccountNumbers((List<Account>)Eval("Accounts"))%>
```

[DataBinder.Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx) returns an `Object` and your method expects a `List<Account>`.

Comment: Does it make any significance to bind the class collection to a column **Vs** binding it with the property of a class and assigning the list as datasource to the Repeater ?

Comment: In the codebehind accounts keeps coming back as null. Any reason for that?

Comment: It's not a List of Account object. You could change your method signature to parseAccountNumbers(object accounts). Then set a break point and expect the object and it's Type.

Comment: As @JoeTuskan says, changing the method signature means you can set a break point. It also means you can catch cast exceptions and it keeps your markup cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea: instead of `parseAccountNumbers(...)`Create a public property (if possible) inside `Documents` class like:

```
public string AccountNumbers
{
    return Accounts.Aggregate("", (current, account) => current + (account.AccountNumber + "<br/>"));       
}
```

and use it as a datafield like:

```
<asp:Boundfield DataField="AccountNumbers" HeaderText="Account#" />
```